# Can set command cause more CPU usage?

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora, cpu

Im running AWS aurora 5.7. The application stack is PHP. After moving to Aurora, I noticed that the CPU consumption is really high. When I checked the performance insights, its showing the SET command is consuming more. (Green colour is CPU)
[image]

And I checked the Aurora Billed Read IOPS, which is almost zero, I think most of them are in InnoDB buffer pool, I didn't see any slow queries, all are executed within a second.

So what Im thinking, the number of SQL queries on this server is a bit high, and thats why the Set command is showing more CPU.

[image]

Can someone help to understand this?

Comment: What does the slowlog say?

Comment: nothing is there, the max long-running query time is 2sec

Comment: Lower it to "0.2"; maybe it will pick up some fast but frequent queries.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
What is AWS AURORA type being used? Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `CPU time` as a single metric is never helpful. I'm well aware that all monitoring software show it, but still. You should look at specific types of CPU times instead, like `iowait`, to find out if `SET NAMES` is making the CPU work or is blocked by other operations..

Anyway, the library you use to connect MySQL could have an option to disable `SET NAMES`. All [`SET NAMES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-names.html) does is to set a session value for [`character_set_client`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client), [`character_set_connection`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection), and [`character_set_results`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_results).

So, in your case, you can disable `SET NAMES=utf8` and set these server variables:

```
character_set_client=utf8
character_set_connection=utf8
character_set_results=utf8
```

If the overall CPU time remains unchanged, `SET NAMES` was probably just waiting for something else.

Comment: Yes the other wait  `io/table/sql/handler` is the most resource-consuming wait.